# Import Column A and B from a existing file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code to pull 2 columns on a existing closed workbook, how do i manage to mix them?

```
   Sub CopyColumnToWorkbookA()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range
Set sourceColumn = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\res\res.xlsx", False, True).Worksheets(1).Columns("A")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Caltoday.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("A")
sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End Sub
   Sub CopyColumnToWorkbookB()
Dim sourceColumnb As Range, targetColumnb As Range
Set sourceColumnb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\res\res.xlsx", False, True).Worksheets(1).Columns("B")
Set targetColumnb = Workbooks("Caltoday.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("B")
sourceColumnb.Copy Destination:=targetColumnb
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

I don't want to open the workbook twice, but I've tried to mix them with no success, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to close twice, just combine in one sub.  The below is a little more "wordy" than necessary, but I kept it like that so you can learn and see a way to do it.

```
Sub copyColumn()
Dim sourceWB As Workbook
Dim sourceWS As Worksheet

Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\res\res.xlsx", False, True)
Set sourceWS = sourceWB.Worksheets(1)

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 2
    sourceWS.Columns(i).Copy Workbooks("Caltoday.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns(i)
Next i

sourceWB.Close False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Or just do

```
SourceWS.Columns("A:B").Copy Workbooks("Caltoday.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("A:B")
```

Answer (score 1):

Get both columns at the same time. Then use your copy to paste them at the same time.

```
Set sourceColumn = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\res\res.xlsx", False, True).Worksheets(1).Columns("A:B")

Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Caltoday.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("A:B")
```

Answer (score 0):

My 0.02 cents

```
Sub copyColumn()
    With Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\res\res.xlsx", False, True) ‘ open and reference source workbook
        .Worksheets(1).Columns("A:B").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Caltoday.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Columns("A:B") ‘ copy referenced workbook sheet 1 columns A: B and paste into Caltoday workbook sheet 2 same columns
        .Close False ‘close referenced workbook discarding changes
    End With
End Sub
```